map a keyboard key symbols to a function key
i'm using an old laptop  from 2013 still ok mainly a bit slow anyway
i want to do some programming but... my main keyboard #9 key with the left parenthesis does not work anymore i can manage the 9 with the num  keypad but as you all know writing programs we need the left parenthesis on a continual basis
is there a way to map the main #9 key symbols to a function key say f9 for example
either a solution from within ubuntu 20.04 or a small c program kinda like a TSR in ealier pc days.
thanks

It would make more sense to use an external keyboard. You would need a separate map to key for each symbol.

Please edit your question to make it easier to understand. The absence of any punctuation makes the question very hard to read. That will decrease your chance to obtain good answers.

after fishing around here is my solution to my own question
9=18
6=15
8=17
f keys
f6=72
f7=73
f8=74
f9=75
at
https://dev.to/bitecode/remap-keys-in-the-keyboard-in-ubuntu-5a36
i found
xmodmap -pke > .Xmodmap
open the .Xmodmap file and find key codes within
for example keycode  38 = a A a A
then change key codes for example
keycode 112 = Prior NoSymbol Prior
keycode 117 = Next NoSymbol Next
is changed to
keycode 112 = KP_Left KP_4 KP_Left KP_4
keycode 117 = KP_Right KP_6 KP_Right KP_6
Now save the file,
in my case it was
keycode  75 = 9 parenleft 4 dollar 9 parenleft 9 parenleft
**** then the info goes on to
and activate the key map: with $ xmodmap .Xmodmap
but this just freeze my computer !!
so ... i reboot and try something else
at How do I set Xmodmap on login?
i found near the bottom
xdg run scripts in ~/.config/autostart upon login in a X session. To load xmodmap config upon login, add the following script to ~/.config/autostart/xmodmap.desktop:
[Desktop Entry]
Name[en_US]=Xmodmap
Comment[en_US]=xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
Exec=/usr/bin/xmodmap .Xmodmap
Icon=application-default-icon
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Type=Application
Then logout and login again, and your Xmodmap configuration should've been loaded.
If it's not working, try to run xmodmap in terminal to see if it's xmodmap that complains:
$ xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
so i did
$ mkdir ~/.config/autostart
$ sudo nano ~/.config/autostart/xmodmap.desktop
put in  the code above
saved the file xmodmap.desktop
checked with
$ cat  ~/.config/autostart/xmodmap.desktop
and logout and login again
and it worked
now i get a 9 with f9 key
now i get a left parenthesis with  shift-f9 key
((((((999999((((())))) with my f9 key
great!!!
other maybe helpful References
https://medium.com/@saplos123456/persistent-keyboard-mapping-on-ubuntu-using-xmodmap-cd01ad828fcd
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49650/how-to-get-keycodes-for-xmodmap


What is this? It is not clear and I can not tell what it is.
